# Smoke transparency render perfect in blender, but altered after saving

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to render a cigar with a smoke simulation on transparency alpha png.
In the viewport and the render, the smoke looks perfect,
[image]

but when i'm saving the image for composite, the smoke opacity gets altered as you can see in illustrator (png on black background).
[image]

I'm using basic render and saving settings (png,16 cdepth,with and without comp) but it is still the same.
It's very frustrating because the render looks perfect in blender.

Thanks a lot ! :)

EDIT : my composition
[image]
my save settings
[image]

EDIT2 : I found that the alpha canal in the composite render is different to
the color canal. Maybe it can be helpfull to find the problem.
[image]
[image]

EDIT3 : FOUND THE WAY
[image]

Comment: Can you share your save options screenshot, on Render window (Fig. 1) > Shift + Alt + S and take screen shot.

Comment: I edited the original post ! :)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce your issue. I also try on Cycle and Evee but it both fine.

Comment: I made an edit it may be usefull. Why is it making these line?

Comment: Not certain, but it sounds suspiciously like the ancient Blender broken alpha thing. PNG is also a broken format, so avoid it. Blender has had broken alpha encoding for file output forever. Sadly, TIFF should work, but it too is broken. You’ll need to save to EXR to get proper handling.

Comment: I got it thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: @a33 Would you mind sharing how are your solve this problem?

Comment: yes check the edit !

Comment: It is very hard to match the render and the png output :/ 
but after playing with the density and some math node on multiply plus colorramp I have managed to get a decent result. What confused me is the emission that not really showing on the png but very visible on the render.